# VCL - configuration for Magento and Varnish 3.0.2

Tags: configuration, reverse-proxy, cache, varnish, magento

I would like to kindly ask if there's someone who can help me configure Varnish for Magento
to reach far more hits. My current ratio from varnishstat is:

1. `cache_hit=271`
2. `cache_miss=926`

I'm kindly asking this because I've googled almost every site related to this theme, but 99.9% of configurations don't work because of outdated code.

**Details** of my set-up:

- I use Varnish on port 80, Apache on port 81,
- PageCache as Magento varnish module,
- APC for PHP speed and Memcached for dynamic caching.
- Load speed is about 1.5s on home-page (Pingdom.com average results) > USA ping & 2.5s > Europe.
- Servers are located in Toronto, Canada.

EDIT:

This is my full VCL configuration > http://pastebin.com/885BzHCs
(I just use xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx for my IPs)
This is the info from the command (varnishtop -i TxHeader -I Cookie):

```
TxHeader Cookie: frontend=965b5...(*lots of numbers); adminhtml=3ae65...(*lots of numbers); EXTERNAL_NO_CACHE=1
```

"(*lots of numbers)" is just my adding to the info

Any idea how to avoid Varnish hitting this cookies? (If I got correctly the idea about avoiding Vanrish hitting the cookie and not caching the home page).

Thank you for any help!

Comment: Welcome to serverfault. Don't post in the answers section, click edit and update your question. This is a Q&A site not a forum.

Answer (score 0):

I don't work with Magento, but here are some Varnish suggestions that have worked for me:

**Check for Cookies**

First, you should remove all cookies from hitting varnish, 'cos when varnish sees a cookie, it sends the request to the backend.

Use a command like this to see what cookies are being sent to the backend:

```
varnishtop -i TxHeader -I Cookie
```

**vcl_hash**

Second, evaluate if you really need `vcl_hash`. If you don't have a reason for using it, comment it out.

Try these one at a time and see if your hit ratio improves.

HTH, good luck.

Comment: Thank you! Yeah, I clearly understand this functionalities, but I can't find any proper code to use it correctly (I mean to remove concrete cookies right). They have strange names etc, etc and I would be sad to break any Magento's core functionalities, that I can't see by simple testing the frontend. I would try your suggestions for sure! :) Thanks again! If anything comes to your mind, feel free to share, it would be greatly appreciated!